# Remove bundleId from Personal Team on AppStore Connect

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode, app-store-connect

I have a strange problem with Apple Developer account and I don’t know how to solve it.

Today I purchased the licence for $99/year for the first time ever ))
I was working on 2 apps and defined the bundle identifiers (com.company.appname1 and com.company.appname2) and had them registered on Personal Team (under Signing & Capabilities tab in Xcode). The problem is that I can’t re-register the same bundle identifiers under the newly created team with payed membership.

Did you encounter this issue previously and how did you solve it?

I just sent an email to Apple Support, but I’m in a rush with the launch and can’t wait 2 days to get an answer.
At least I need to know if it’s possible to remove the bundle ids from the personal team to make them available to re-register

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you had an account that had the Free Developer license, but now you have purchased the Developer Program License. If this assumption is correct, you cannot re-use the Bundle ID as it has already been registered with a different account.

Comment: You understood me correctly. In the end I could reuse the bundleId in code (check my answer) but I couldn't sign the app with that bundleId. So yeah, it cannot be reused.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved the issue.

I had to go to Signing & Capabilities -> All

Make sure that on both sub-tabs, Debug and Release I had Personal Team, then type in a random BundleId

After that I switched back to my company Team (payed) and type in the desired bundle Id.

Happy ending story )))